# Different translations for different locations - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I'm trying to develop an internationalized app with different translations for each country. For instance, I would like to get a different translation for spanish people than for the mexican ones, or a different translation for english people than for the american ones. What would be the best way to implement this approach?. I already got a table 'culture' on my DB where I store values like the currency or the flag image path for each country. Would be possible have different language files for each country?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php

Comment: Thanks for the interest, but i'm looking for an option relying on the framework.